# how to load wordpress comments using ajax when user scroll upto comment div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have been trying to do this past 2 days but no success.

here is my code.

```
var elementOffse = $('#loadComments').offset().top;

var heigh = $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    var scrollTopp = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTopp >= (elementOffse - heigh) && loaded == 0)
        {

            loaded = 1;
            $('#loadComments').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "loadComments.php"
        }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
        $('#loadComments').html(data); // display data
        });             

    }
});
```

in loadComments.php i call the function 'comments_template();'.

i want to load the comments in #loadComments after it is queried.

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: does data actually get populated?

Comment: it shows only "downloading...". after that nothing happens.

Comment: have you console.log(data) in the .done function? to see if that is even working?

Comment: i am new to ajax and php, and i have no idea how to troubleshoot this further. i don't think its working.

Comment: quick and dirty way, in the done function add alert(data); you'll get a popup if that's firing

Comment: its not firing. no alert.

Comment: Does your server have any errors?

Comment: no the server has no error.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a built in AJAX handler, and using this ensures that your AJAX requests can access all the goodness of WP.

I can't say for sure without seeing logs, but if you are doing something with comments, it's likely that a WP core function is involved, and as a generic AJAX call won't include them, an error could be thrown.

Here is some JS that should do the trick -

```
var elementOffse = $('#loadComments').offset().top;

var heigh = $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollTopp = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTopp >= (elementOffse - heigh) && loaded == 0){

        loaded = 1;
        $('#loadComments').html('Downloading...'); // Show "Downloading..."

        var data = {
            type:       'GET',
            action:     'load-comments'
        };

        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            $('#loadComments').html(response);
        });           

    }
});
```

PHP - Place this in `functions.php` (or any other custom included file if you wish) -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' ); // If user is not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' ); // If user is logged in
function my_ajax(){

    {...do your comments stuff here...}

    die();  // Required for a proper Wordpress AJAX result

}
```

Finally, to ensure AJAX requests for non-logged in users (the nopriv hook) are handeled correctly, add this to `functions.php` (or any other custom included file if you wish).

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'plugin_set_ajax_url');
function plugin_set_ajax_url() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajax_object = {};
        ajax_object.ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I have called the function 'comments_template();' inside my_ajax function, but there comes no output (#loadComments is loaded with empty string but initially it did show downloading...). I tried to echo something inside my_ajax function, but it show nothing. Any idea why it is not showing the output?

Comment: I've made a slight change to the JS. I noticed that where I copied part of your code, you were using `data`, but I was passing `response` (it makes no difference which you use). Thus in if you copied that code, `data` would be null...

Comment: now I am getting the output as '0', when I echo something or when I call comments_template(); inside my_ajax function. Can u give me a hint of which code to write inside my_ajax function if I want to get the comments of a particular post?

Comment: Unfortunately my experience of WP does not stretch to using the Comments system. What I would suggest though is trying to call the function when the page loads, that way you'll be able to see any errors that may be found; it just makes debugging a bit easier, before then implementing the AJAX solution.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try to implement the way you suggested.